# Calling multiple functions to one value in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

Probably an beginner question. When a counter I have on my page hits 10000 I am looking to reset the number to 1 and show "+10k" next to it.

For example, if the counter response was 10010 it would display as follows:
[Image of UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVaxE.png)

Is there a more efficient way of doing the following:

- Set one ID to reset the number to 1 when it hits 10000
- Change the display settings of another ID when API response value hits 10000

  // below changes 10000 to 1

  ```
    function kFormatter(num) {
        if (num > 1 && num < 10000) {
        return Math.abs(num) ? Math.sign(num)*((Math.abs(num)-0).toFixed(1)): Math.sign(num)*Math.abs(num)

    }
        else if (num > 10000 && num < 20000) {
          return Math.abs(num) ? Math.sign(num)*((Math.abs(num)-500).toFixed(1)): Math.sign(num)*Math.abs(num)
    }
    }

    // Below script shows +10k copy

    function show10k(num) {
        if (num > 1 && num < 10000) {
                document.getElementById("10k-text").style.display = "none";

    }
        else if (num > 10000 && num < 20000) {
                document.getElementById("10k-text").style.display = "flex";
    }
    }

    // output

    function websiteVisits(response) {
            document.querySelector("#visits").textContent = (kFormatter, show10k)(response.value);
    }
  ```

Comment: You can compose a single statement, containing two function calls, like so: `show10k(kFormatter(response.value));`

Answer (score 0):

1. first : `function kFormatter(num)` of you is wrong :
   `(Math.abs(num)-500)` should change to `(Math.abs(num)-10000)`
2. `(kFormatter, show10k)` is returned `show10k` ([document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)):

- `(kFormatter, show10k)(response.value)` <=> `show10k(response.value)`

3. You can call 2 function same as :

```
document.querySelector("#visits").textContent = kFormatter(response.value);
show10k(response.value)
```

or call `show10k()` in `kFormatter()` same as :

```
function kFormatter(num) {
  if (num > 1 && num < 10000) {
    show10k("none")
    return Math.abs(num) ? Math.sign(num)*((Math.abs(num)-0).toFixed(1)): 
    Math.sign(num)*Math.abs(num)
  } else if (num > 10000 && num < 20000) {
    show10k("flex")
    return Math.abs(num) ? Math.sign(num)*((Math.abs(num)-10000).toFixed(1)): 
    Math.sign(num)*Math.abs(num)
  }
}

// Below script shows +10k copy

function show10k(display) {
   document.getElementById("10k-text").style.display = display;
}
```

Example :

```js
const valueInput = document.getElementById('number');
const formatNumber = (value) => {
  return parseInt(value)
}
valueInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
  valueInput.value = formatNumber(this.value);
  websiteVisits(this.value)
});

const kFormatter = num => {
  let visit = num%10000
  let xk = parseInt(num/10000)
  showxk(xk)
  return visit
}

  // Below script shows +10k copy

const showxk = xk => {
  let xkEle  = document.getElementById("xk-text");
  if (!xk) {
    xkEle.classList.add('hide')
  } else {
    xkEle.classList.remove('hide')
    xkEle.textContent = (Math.sign(xk) > 0 ? '+' : '') + xk + '0k'
  }
}

const websiteVisits = value => {
  document.querySelector("#visits").textContent = kFormatter(value)
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<span id="visits"></span><sup id='xk-text' class="hide"></sup>
<hr />
<input type="number" id="number" step="1">
```

Comment: This looks like a much cleaner approach and works well on the number abbreviation. show10k, I can't get that to work though. I adjusted it slightly to test with smaller numbers but thought it should work. Have I messed something up?

`function kFormatter(num) {
  if (num > 1 && num < 100) {
    show10k("none")
    return Math.abs(num) ? Math.sign(num)*((Math.abs(num)-0).toFixed(1)): 
   Math.sign(num)*Math.abs(num)
  } else  {
    show10k("flex")
    return Math.abs(num) ? Math.sign(num)*((Math.abs(num)-10000).toFixed(1)): 
    Math.sign(num)*Math.abs(num)
  }
}`

Comment: This is how I am trying to output the results, may this is my problem:
`// output

function websiteVisits(response) {
        document.querySelector("#visits").textContent = kFormatter(response.value);
        document.getElementById("tenktext").innerHTML = showtenk(response.value);

}`

Comment: please show your `response.value` . ex : `10000043` or `-32353334,43` ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the constraints of your project but this is how I would achieve the same thing:

```
if (input.value > 10000) {

    let tenKays = Math.floor(input.value / 10000)

    let digits = input.value % 10000

    output.innerHTML = digits + " " + "+" + tenKays + "0K"

} else {

    output.innerHTML = input.value

}
```

It could be polished in different ways to display the actual output in a more sophisticated way but it's a simple method that handles numbers of any size.